# I need to choose a compression algorithm

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, compression

I need to choose a compression algorithm to compress some data. I don't know the type of data I'll be compressing in advance (think of it as kinda like the WinRAR program).

I've heard of the following algorithms but I don't know which one I should use. Can anyone post a short list of pros and cons? For my application the first priority is decompression speed; the second priority is space saved. Compression (not decompression) speed is irrelevant.

- Deflate
- Implode
- Plain Huffman
- bzip2
- lzma

Comment: Some languages have built-in support for some (maybe all) of these, so you could do some quick testing. I guess this is hard if you don't know the type of data you're going to be compressing, but hopefully you have *some* idea, or some way of randomly generating data that is close to what you'll be using, in some way.

Comment: that is 'some data'? any hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need high decompression speed then you should be using LZO. Its compression speed and ratio are decent, but it's hard to beat its decompression speed.

Comment: wow thanks! Never heard of it before but it seems exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 11):

I ran a few benchmarks compressing a .tar that contained a mix of high entropy data and text. These are the results:

```
Name  - Compression rate* - Decompression Time
7zip  - 87.8%             - 0.703s
bzip2 - 80.3%             - 1.661s
gzip  - 72.9%             - 0.347s
lzo   - 70.0%             - 0.111s

*Higher is better
```

From this I came to the conclusion that the compression rate of an algorithm depends on its name; the first in alphabetical order will be the one with the best compression rate, and so on.

Therefore I decided to rename `lzo` to `1lzo`. Now I have the best algorithm ever.

---

**EDIT**: worth noting that of all of them unfortunately `lzo` is the only one with a very restrictive license (GPL) :(

Comment: +1 for an astounding discovery! It seems that this holds true also for video compression, but in the reverse direction: x264 > XviD > DivX ;) (case sensitive sorting ;))

Comment: "very restrictive license (GPL)" -- /me revives age-old BSD vs GPL argument: restrictive for you the developer but not for the end user! :)

Answer (score 4):

In the Linux kernel it is well explained (from those included):

- Deflate (gzip) - Fast, worst compression
- bzip2 - Slow, middle compression
- lzma - Very slow compression, fast decompression (however slower than gzip), best compression

I haven't use others, so it is hard to say, but speeds of algorithms may depend largely on architecture. For example, there are studies that data compression on the HDD speeds the I/O, as the processor is so much faster than the disk that it is worth it. However, it depends largely on the size of bottlenecks.

Similarly, one algorithm may use memory extensively, which may or may not cause problems (12 MiB -- is it a lot or very small?  On embedded systems it is a lot; on a modern x86 it is tiny fragment of memory).

Comment: Note that *deflate* is a *data format* while *gzip* is a *file format* that uses *deflate* to compress the files.

Comment: The option in Linux kernel is called gzip (how to compress kernel/initrd). So I included it as well.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/7z.html). It's open source and contains 7 separate compression methods. Some minor testing we've done shows the 7z format gives a much smaller result file than zip and it was also faster for the sample data we used.

Since our standard compression is zip, we didn't look at other compression methods yet.

Answer (score 1):

For a comprehensive benchmark on text data you might want to check out the [Large Text Compression Benchmark](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text.html).

For other types, [this might be indicative](http://www.maximumcompression.com/index.html).

Comment: And what about other types of data?

Comment: However, I should add that it generally depends on the data.
(That is why it is only *indicative*.)